# Creating a partitioned table from query in Big Query does not yield same as without partitioning

Tags: google-bigquery, database-partitioning

When creating a table let's say "orders" with partitioning in the following way my result gets truncated in comparison to if I create it without partitioning. (Commenting and uncommenting rows five and 6).

I suspect that it might have something to do with the BQ limits (found [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#partitioned_tables)) but I can't figure out what. The ts is a timestamp field and order_id is a UUID string.

i.e. The count distinct on the last row will yield very different results. When partitioned it will return far less order_ids than without partitioning.

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS
  `project.dataset.orders`;
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  `project.dataset.orders`
-- PARTITION BY 
--   DATE(ts)
AS
SELECT
  ts,
  order_id,
  SUM(order_value) AS order_value
FROM
  `project.dataset.raw_orders`
GROUP BY
  1, 2;

SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) FROM  `project.dataset.orders`;
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there's a 60 day partition expiration!
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-tables#partition-expiration

So by updating the partition expiration I could get the full range.